# UPDATE record based on record from previous day

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I'm trying to write a MySQL query that will compare two records within the same table and save it's two day average.

My table holds information from different sites and has one record saved to it per weekday, per site. There are many sites, so there will be many records saved on the same day, but all I care about is comparing the same sites across two days. Each weekday morning the table is updated with information and after that job finishes, I want to run a query that will look at the new values, compare it to the same site on the previous day and update the column 'change' for that same day. My table looks like this right now:

```
sitename      date       value1  change
 site1      2018-02-20      1      0
 site2      2018-02-20      2      0
 site3      2018-02-20      5      0
 site1      2018-02-16      3      0  
 site2      2018-02-16      4      0  
 site3      2018-02-16      7      0  
 site1      2018-02-15      2      0  
 site2      2018-02-15      9      0  
 site3      2018-02-15      3      0
```

I want my query to look at the value of site1 on 2018-02-20, subtract it from the value of site1 on 2018-02-16 and save that value into column change on 2018-02-20 (Feb 19 not included since it's a holiday & Feb 17, 18 are weekends). Also I'm trying to run this query where change = 0, so if I don't run it one day it will recognize the previous days that didn't get ran and update those days as well.

Lastly, different sites are added at different times, so the sites all have records going back to different dates. For example site2 has an initial record of 2018-02-01 whereas site1 goes back to 2017-01-01. So the column change for site2 on 2018-02-01 will remain 0 and change will also remain 0 for site1 on 2017-01-01 (because there are no previous records).

I hope this isn't too confusing. Thank you in advance for any help or guidance anyone can provide.

Desired result for the data above:

```
sitename      date       value1  change
 site1      2018-02-20      1     -2
 site2      2018-02-20      2     -2
 site3      2018-02-20      5     -2
 site1      2018-02-16      3      1  
 site2      2018-02-16      4     -5  
 site3      2018-02-16      7      4  
 site1      2018-02-15      2      0  
 site2      2018-02-15      9      0  
 site3      2018-02-15      3      0
```

Comment: Please add your desired result.

Comment: For this specific data set above, the desired result I've posted above.

Comment: Is there any order in your current data?

Comment: The order is: date desc, sitename

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> select t2.sitename, 
>        t2.dt, 
>        t2.value1,
>        coalesce (t2.value1 - (select t1.value1 
>                               from tbl t1 
>                               where t1.sitename = t2.sitename 
>                               and t2.dt > t1.dt 
>                               order by t1.sitename, t1.dt desc
>                               limit 1), 0) chg
> from   tbl t2
> order by t2.dt desc, t2.sitename;
> ```
>
> ```
> sitename | dt         | value1 | chg
> :------- | :--------- | -----: | --:
> site1    | 2018-02-20 |      1 |  -2
> site2    | 2018-02-20 |      2 |  -2
> site3    | 2018-02-20 |      5 |  -2
> site1    | 2018-02-16 |      3 |   1
> site2    | 2018-02-16 |      4 |  -5
> site3    | 2018-02-16 |      7 |   4
> site1    | 2018-02-15 |      2 |   0
> site2    | 2018-02-15 |      9 |   0
> site3    | 2018-02-15 |      3 |   0
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=6e0172f12365c4a84980f73aa139c60f)*

If you want to update `change` column you can execute next query:

> Note: It assumes that every pair (sitename,dt) is unique.

> ```
> update tbl t
>   join 
>   ( select t2.sitename, t2.dt, 
>            coalesce(t2.value1 - tu.value1, 0) as new_value1
>     from tbl t2
>       join tbl tu
>     on  tu.sitename = t2.sitename 
>     and tu.dt = 
>     ( select t1.dt 
>       from   tbl t1 
>       where  t1.sitename = t2.sitename 
>       and    t2.dt > t1.dt 
>       order by t1.sitename, t1.dt desc
>       limit 1
>     ) 
>   ) as tu
>   on  t.sitename = tu.sitename
>   and t.dt = tu.dt
> set    t.chg = new_value1 ;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> select *
> from   tbl
> order by dt desc, sitename
> ```
>
> ```
> sitename | dt         | value1 | chg
> :------- | :--------- | -----: | --:
> site1    | 2018-02-20 |      1 |  -2
> site2    | 2018-02-20 |      2 |  -2
> site3    | 2018-02-20 |      5 |  -2
> site1    | 2018-02-16 |      3 |   1
> site2    | 2018-02-16 |      4 |  -5
> site3    | 2018-02-16 |      7 |   4
> site1    | 2018-02-15 |      2 |   0
> site2    | 2018-02-15 |      9 |   0
> site3    | 2018-02-15 |      3 |   0
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=5f1cd8b55417284918b4a682d271b798)*

Comment: Thank you very much, this works. If I want to take the chg field and use it to update the column I created, how do I do that? Can I append an update stmt to this query somehow?

Comment: With some adjustments, the update code helped me enormously, so thanks for that. I kept getting a MySQL error of "You can't specify target table 't' for update in FROM clause" so I ended up using a separate (basically a copy of the outer table) table in the inner joins which worked well, if rather slowly - about 60 seconds to update ~25000 rows. But I could live with that in a cron job.